# SQL Join in Codeigniter on two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I am building a url shortening / redirect service and I'm a bit confused as to how I can best get the data from two tables.

I have two tables like so:

**redirects**

```
id
datetime
ip_address
browser_agent
url_string
```

**links**

```
id
alias
url
created
user_id
```

***Links*** stores the link details and every time there is a redirect it's logged in the ***redirects*** table as a single row for each redirect.

`alias` in ***links*** and `url_string` in ***redirects*** are the same. e.g. `Dw4` so the domain would be `example.com/Dw4` - redirects to the `url` field in ***links***.

What I'm trying to achieve is to select (and count) all redirects from the ***redirects*** table where the `url_string` is same as `alias` and then where `user_id` is the same as the logged-in user.

I am using Codeigniter.

So far I'm trying to go for something like this:

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * " . "FROM links, redirects " . "WHERE links.alias = redirects.url_string");
```

But I'm having no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` the two tables like so:

```
SELECT 
  r.*
FROM redirects r
INNER JOIN links l ON r.url_string = l.alias;
```

---

**Update:** Try this:

```
SELECT 
  l.*,
  r.browser_agent,
  rCounts.redirectsCount
FROM links l
INNER JOIN redirects r ON r.url_string = l.alias
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT url_string, COUNT(*) redirectsCount
   FROM redirects 
   GROUP BY url_string
) rCounts ON rrCounts.url_string = l.alias;
```

Comment: Ok that joins them perfect. But how would I work off the links table instead. What i mean is just load one row per link rather than one per redirect?

Comment: @Chris Can you please explain what exactly to select from these two tables? For the example you posted in your question the `example.com/Dw4` how this should be selected from the two tables, does the `exampl.com` is coming from which field? Thanks.

Comment: OK, what im trying to do is list all the links a user has created, So select * from links where user = $uid. Then in that table i also want to be able to provide a count on how many redirects that link got based on the data from the redirects table. Thanks

Comment: Ok that is brilliant. One last thing. I can no longer access things like browser_agent from the redirects table. What do i need to do to use that? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Chris There  are several ways to do so, one way is to add an extra `JOIN` like in my updated answer. See my edit. If any you need any other thing or anything goes wrong don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks, that works except it seems to have reverted back to showing all redirects rather than just one row per link. Sorry, SQL is not my strong point!

Comment: Sorry ignore me. That didnt make sense. What i have is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` for this as:

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('links');
    $this->db->join('redirects', 'redirects.url_string = links.alias');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result;
```

and in **view** use `foreach` syntax to display the db-contents as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As when you said, user_id should be same for logged user, you should use join with 
user_id also to get particular user_id details, So your query should be like :

```
SELECT redirects.id,count(*) FROM redirects inner join links 
on redirects.url_string=links.alias
and redirects.id=links.user_id
group by redirects.id
```